# How can I convert .txt file into a list python?

Tags: python, list, nested-lists

Within the .txt file:

```
[['Courtney fan', 'https://www.aaa.com', 'he is a good guy'], ['Courtney fan', 'https://www.bbb.com', 'Dave Butner', 'https://www.ccc.com', 'Austin']]
```

I tried this method, but it doesn't split properly:

```
with open("/Users/jj/Desktop/Courtney_fan.txt","r") as f:
       sd = f.read().split()
```

How can I write this into a nested list in python?

Comment: [\[Python\]: json.loads()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads) (after replacing `'` by `"`)?

Comment: This looks like valid `json`. Just import the `json` module and use the `load` function within it.

Comment: It is already in the form of the list inside a text file. Check how to read txt file its simple. Read the input/output (i/o) documentation of python.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the data is a valid python literal (list, dict etc..) you can use the `literal_eval` function from pythons built-in `ast` package. This is better than a solution using `eval` as it will only evaluate a valid data structure, and does not allow arbitrary code execution. There are almost zero cases where using plain `eval` is a good idea.

```
from ast import literal_eval

with open("/Users/jj/Desktop/Courtney_fan.txt","r") as f:
    my_list = literal_eval(f.read())
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to open the file and read it. json should do this for you.
What have you tried? And why didn't it work?

```
import json

with open(".txt") as f:
    l = json.load(f)
```

Answer (score 0):

As your  `.txt` file appears to be correct formatted and ist read in as a `string` the build in function `eval()` does this for you.

Here an example which is similar to your string in the txt-file:

```
test = "['a', ['b','c']]"
>>> trial = eval(test)
>>> type(trial)
<class 'list'>
>>> trial
['a', ['b', 'c']]
```

For you it would then be:

```
with open("/Users/jj/Desktop/Courtney_fan.txt") as f:
       sd = f.read()

sd_list = eval(sd)
```